# Number of possible polynomials satisfying $[P(x)]^2+[Q(x)]^2=x^{2n}+1$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Given that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How many pairs of $P(x),\;Q(x)$ (all coefficients of $P$ and $Q$ are real numbers) with $deg\; P > deg\; Q$ satisfying: $[P(x)]^2+[Q(x)]^2=x^{2n}+1$?

---

I found an answer [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h177238p24336021). It goes like this (only the part relevant to this post):

> The answer is $2^{n+1}$.
> Let the roots of $x^{2n}+1$ be $r_1, \overline{r_1}, \cdots, r_n, \overline{r_n}$. Then observe the way to factor it into irreducibles in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is $(x-r_j)(x-\overline{r_j})$.
> Since $\deg P<\deg Q=n$ it follows that $\deg(P+iQ)=n$.
> Claim: $P+iQ$ is divisible by exactly one of $r_i, \overline{r_i}$ for each $1\le i\le n$.
> Proof: If it is divisible by both then $x^{2n}+1$ has double root. If it is divisible by neither, $x^{2n}+1$ is not divisible by $r_i$.
> .....

---

In their claim that $P+iQ$ is divisible by exactly one of $r_i, \overline{r_i}$ for each $1\le i\le n$, they said if it is divisible by both then $x^{2n}+1$ has double root. Can anyone explain how does a double root come? Thanks

Comment: By  the fundamental theorem of algebra, polynomials with real coefficients may have real roots. All complex, non real roots may be sorted  in pairs of complex conjugates. They produce the  quadratic positive, real irreducible factors $x^2+ a_i^2= x^2+ r_j \overline r_j$

Comment: @RolandF It's not the fundamental theorem of algebra that says that (it says nothing about where the roots are, and nothing special about real polynomials). And that's not what the irreducible quadratic factors are (consider $x^2-2x+2$, for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P+iQ$ is divisible by both $r_j$ and $\overline{r_j}$ then
$$
 P(z)+iQ(z) = (z-r_j)(z-\overline{r_j}) R(z)
$$
with some (complex) polynomial $R$. Since $P$ and $Q$ have real coefficients is
$$
 P(z) -iQ(z) = \overline{P(\bar z) + i Q(\bar z)}
= (z-\overline{r_j})(z-r_j) \overline{R(\bar z)}
$$
and therefore
$$
\begin{align}
 z^{2n+1} + 1 &= P(z)^2 + Q(z)^2 \\
 &=(P(z)+iQ(z))(P(z)-iQ(z)) \\
 &= (z-r_j)^2(z-\overline{r_j})^2 R(z)\overline{R(\bar z)}
\end{align}
$$
so that $ z^{2n+1} + 1$ would have both $r_j$ and $\overline{r_j}$ as double zeros, which is not possible.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Can you please tell why $P(z) -iQ(z) = \overline{P(\bar z) + i Q(\bar z)}$? I know that $P(x)-iQ(x)$ is the conjugate of $P(x)+iQ(x)$, so I thought it should have been $P(z) -iQ(z) = \overline{P(z) + i Q( z)}$

Comment: @zaemon_23: $\overline{P(\bar z)} = P(z)$ because $P$ has real coefficients, and the same  for $Q$. – Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: thanks! Although a bit different doubt, why can't $X^{2n}+1$ have complex double roots though?

Comment: @zaemon_23: Because the derivative has no zeros except at the origin.

Comment: @zaemon_23: Is anything still unclear?

Comment: oh no, I'm very sorry I forgot to green tick the answer. And no, I don't have any doubt unchecked. Thanks a lot :)